# Regex to exclude a substring

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a param string but exclude any matches when a substring is present.

From my limited regex knowledge this should work to exlude any string containing "porcupine", but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

`(\/animal\?.*(?!porcupine).*color=white)`

**Expected Outcome**

```
| string                                          | matches? |
| ----------------------------------------------- | -------- |
| /animal?nose=wrinkly&type=porcupine&color=white | false    |
| /animal?nose=wrinkly&type=puppy&color=white     | true     |
```

**Actual Outcome**

```
| string                                          | matches? |
| ----------------------------------------------- | -------- |
| /animal?nose=wrinkly&type=porcupine&color=white | true     |
| /animal?nose=wrinkly&type=puppy&color=white     | true     |
```

Comment: You should put the `.*` inside the lookahead `\/animal\?(?!.*porcupine).*color=white`

Answer (score 2):

Use a Tempered Greedy Token:

```
/animal\?(?:(?!porcupine).)*color=white
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/3dGK8k/1)

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` searches anything for any number of times, greedily. So you could replace it with a literal search:

```
(\/animal\?nose=wrinkly\&type=(?!porcupine).*color=white)
```

See example here: https://regex101.com/r/HJiM2N/1

Comment: This working only if parameters are in the same order.

Comment: Yes. If they are not, place the `.*` inside the negative lookahead

Answer (score 0):

This may seem overly verbose but it is actually relatively efficient in the number of steps:

```
(?!\/animal.*?porcupine.*?color)\/animal\?.*color=white
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uEKCPz/1/)

If the input string consists of only one and only one occurrence of what you are trying to match and nothing else, then just use the following to ensure that `porcupine` does not occur anywhere in the input string:

```
(?!.*porcupine)\/animal\?.*color=white
```

The code:

```
import re

tests = [
    '/animal?nose=wrinkly&type=porcupine&color=white',
    '/animal?nose=wrinkly&type=puppy&color=white'
]

rex = r'(?!\/animal.*?porcupine.*?color)\/animal\?.*color=white'

for test in tests:
    m = re.search(rex, test)
    print(test, 'True' if m else 'False')
```

Prints:

```
/animal?nose=wrinkly&type=porcupine&color=white False
/animal?nose=wrinkly&type=puppy&color=white True
```